ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'xxxx.csv' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
Trying to export table data using below mysql statement in Windows 10 OS:
mysql> SELECT * FROM classicmodels.customers
    -> INTO OUTFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\xxx.csv'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

which shows below error:
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'C:ProgramDataMySQLMySQL Server 8.0Uploads  xxx.csv' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

Try to give permission the path folders but nothing helped.

OS account which is used for MySQL daemon execution must have according permissions in the filesystem.

This error has nothing to do with access rights (that would be errno 13 - permission denied). Please check out the folder path in the error message...

Try to add double slash ('C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\xxx.csv') in the path statement. It works to me.
